# passing parameter to Http Handler from jQuery call

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to call my custom Htpp Handler and want to pass some parameter's but i am unable to retrieve those param's value on the http Handler process request method.
I use code like ..

At Client Side

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'VideoViewValidation.ashx',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 'Id': '10000', 'Type': 'Employee' },
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    alert('Server Method is called successfully.' + data.d);
                },
                error: function (errorText) {
                    debugger;
                    alert('Server Method is not called due to ' + errorText);
                }
            });
```

And this is on my custom http Handler

```
public class VideoViewValidation : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string videoID = string.Empty;
        string id = context.Request["Id"];
        string type = context.Request["Type"];
}
}
```

Please tell me where is the problem .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove "contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'" and add "dataType:'json'"

Comment: can you tell me its not working when i was using contentType instead of dataType ?

Comment: Remove "debugger;". Use "console" and see if the request is sent and what is the content of the response.

Answer (score 5):

Darm's answer was correct, but just to be clearer about why this works...

You need to remove the line `contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'` so that $.ajax() uses the default of `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` (as specified in the [docs for $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). By doing this alone, your code sample should work (the dataType parameter actually specifies the data type that you're expecting to be **returned** from the server).

In its simplest form, you could write the $.ajax() call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'VideoViewValidation.ashx',
    data: { 'Id': '10000', 'Type': 'Employee' },
});
```

In this case, the request would be made via GET and the parameters would be sent via the query string, but it still works with `context.Request`.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery is sending POST data so you will need to look at the Request.Form["Id"] etc

```
public class VideoViewValidation : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string videoID = string.Empty;
        string id = context.Request.Form["Id"];
        string type = context.Request.Form["Type"];
}
}
```

Comment: I tried it but its not working.
its resulting null value. please try yourself.

Comment: This is covered by Abisheks's original code. The context.Request member has a default indexer that "Gets the specified object from the System.Web.HttpRequest.QueryString, System.Web.HttpRequest.Form, System.Web.HttpRequest.Cookies, or System.Web.HttpRequest.ServerVariables collections.".

Answer (score 0):

Your data is sent to the handler using an ajax call (not from a typical form submit). To retrieve the data you just need context.Request["Id"]. that should do the trick.