# Threading in WinForms Desktop application?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have a dataset which is binded to a datagrid.
In dataset , there is a coulmn which holds status of data . 
On page load, it have 'Pending' values.

Now when i interact with 3rd party software, its values update either 'Success' or 'Failure'.
But these changes reflect on datagrid when all transactions are completed.

I want to show all updated results as per transaction..
using Thread.

please provide me a code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use jQuery with http generic handler in above situation.

Comment: here is a link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828089/passing-parameter-to-http-handler-from-jquery-call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828089/passing-parameter-to-http-handler-from-jquery-call) [http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2010/08/04/parallel-tasks-net-4-0-feature.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2010/08/04/parallel-tasks-net-4-0-feature.aspx)

Comment: window or web application??

Comment: and in tags you have mentioned asp.net?

Comment: Yeah, what the heck is an asp.net desktop application?

Comment: OK. Its windows application

Answer (score 2):

You cannot update the DataSet from another thread.  If you do this, the application will result in the Cross Thread operation exception.  The best approach I see is to calculate the required status in a background thread but update the DataSet in the main thread.  This should not affect your application performance. Here is some sample code:

```
...
            ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(UpdateStatuses);
            Thread thread = new Thread(ts);
            thread.Start();
...

        void UpdateStatuses() { 
            // calculate statuses ;
            BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
                for(int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
                    table.Rows[i]["Status"] = someValue;
            }));
        }
```